# Area of $y^2=x^2(a^2-x^2)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Im trying to find the area of $y^2=x^2(a^2-x^2)$ where $a>0$.

From my calculations it seems to be 
$$
2\int_{0}^{a} x\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}dx=\frac{2}{3}a^3,
$$ 
but I am not sure if it is right.

Comment: You are right https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+from+0+to+a+of+2xsqrt(a%5E2-x%5E2)dx&t=crmtb01.

Comment: You know you can put entire equations in dollar signs, right? Not only is it easier to write `$y^2=x^2(a^2-x^2)$` than it is to write `$y^2$=$x^2$($a^2$-$x^2$)`, the end result also looks a whole lot better.